# how to deploy a file to a folder on remote server using maven

Tags: windows, file, maven, pom.xml, scp

I need help to deploy component file on remote server using maven. I have different component files for different environments. Which maven plugins achieves this goal?

Comment: What do you mean by component file? do you mean properties?

Comment: Consider this is a file with comp as extension. I have my artifact in one folder and this file in other folder. This file is needed to start my application after deploying on server.